# Prove or disprove: $n^{\log_2 n} = \mathcal{O}(a^n)$ for all $a > 1$

Tags: asymptotics

I am not sure how to solve this problem:

Prove or disprove: $n^{\log_2 n} = \mathcal{O}(a^n)$ for all $a > 1$

I have tried calculating $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{\log_2 n}}{a^n}$ to see if it equals zero (which would imply that this equals $\mathcal{O}(a^n)$), but I don't think this path would work.

Comment: Note that $n^{\log_2(n)}=a^{\log_2(n)\log_a(n)}=a^{\ln^2(n)/(\ln(2)\ln(a))}$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt how did you get the last equality? And did you mean $ln = log_e$ or did you mean $log_2$?

Comment: It's just change of base formula, and $\ln=\log_e$ is common notation, not that it matters what base it is if you understand the change of base formula.